# Split arraylist<string> into 2 string[] and add to listview

Tags: android, string, arraylist

I'm getting an ArrayList from web service. It has date in the format DDMM. I want to separate the date and month and save them to 2 String[].

```html
ArrayList<String> txt_arr = new ArrayList<String>
txt_arr=add(json_data.getString("date"));  // saving date from json to arraylist
//Here I want to split the arraylist "txt_arr" into 2 String[]
//I tried:
String[] format = txt_arr.toArray(new String[txt_arr.size()])
String[] split = format.split(" ");
String[] date = split[0];
String[] month = split[1];
```

Comment: post your response getting from webservice.

Comment: could tell use String format in `txt_arr ` ArrayList?

Comment: Its giving me error in code because split() cannot be used in String[] only in String. My ArrayList contains values like {"21 Feb", "8 Nov",...}

Comment: And I want to get values like this: String[] date = 21, 8 and String[] month = Feb, Nov so that I can add this in listview

Comment: Cannot resolve method 'split(java.lang.String)'  @Amy

Comment: Post your Json response

Comment: Post your response of json_data.getString("date")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check with this

```
String[] date = new String[txt_arr.size()];
    String[] month = new String[txt_arr.size()];
    for (int i=0; i< txt_arr.size(); i++)
    {
        String format = txt_arr.get(i);
        String[] split = format.split(" ");
        date[i] = split[0];
        month[i] = split[1];
    }
```

Comment: NullPointerException in the line date[i] = split[0];  @justDroid

Comment: what are your txt_arr data?

Comment: check if your `txt_arr` has correct values and its not empty

Comment: Thats okay but are you parsing it correctly and storing in `txt_arr` ?

Comment: … Earlier I was getting the whole date i.e. 04 Feb like this:
TEXT = txt_arr.toArray(new String[txt_arr.size()]); where String[] TEXT={}

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
    String[] date = new String[size];
    String[] month = new String[size];;
    int =0;
    for(String data:txt_arr){
      String[] split = data.split(" ");
      date[i] = split[0];
      month[i] = split[1];
      i++;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is your arrayList of dates in format DDMM, each object in the arraylist is stored in "21 Feb" format string as you mentioned above.

```
ArrayList<String> txt_arr = new ArrayList<String>
txt_arr=add(json_data.getString("date"));  // saving date from json to arraylist
```

Create 2 string array to store date and month.

```
String[] date = new String[txt_arr.size()];
String[] month = new String[txt_arr.size()]
```

And then, just loop through the list.

```
for(int i=0;i<txt_arr.size();i++){
  String[] d = txt_arr[i].split(" ");
  date[i] = d[0];
  month[i] = d[1];
}
```